# Сервер VPS не отдает стили админки и медиа-форму tiny.mce

Tags: django, nginx, сервер, vps, gunicorn

Сервер `VPS` `Ubuntu` + `Nginx` + `Gunicorn`. Статику отдает `Nginx`

Я далеко не специалист в запуске и обслуживании серверов, но недавно запустил на `VPS` два проекта, которые сам и разрабатывал с нуля.На обоих проектах все работает за исключением двух вещей: в админу не подгружаются `CSS` (при этом в папке, откуда `Nginx` берет статику они есть) и не подгружается форма `tiny.mce` на фронте.

Я пытался решить проблему `CSS` админки установкой `Grappelli` - это не сработало, в админке показывался заголовок `Grappelli`, но стилей по-прежнему не было.

А по `tiny.mce` у меня вообще по нулям.

Мой файл `/etc/nginx/sites-available/project`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/username/projectdir/project;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Мой файл `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target


[Service]
User=username
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/username/projectdir/project
ExecStart=/home/username/projectdir/project/myvenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          config.wsgi:application


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

В журналах никаких ошибок нет.

Кто шарит в теме, поодскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Сам проект не django случайно?

Comment: @Dmitry именно он, забыл тэг добавить

Comment: `collectstatic` пользуетесь для сбора всей статики в одну папку? Или статика у вас разбросана по всему проекту?

Comment: @Dmitry конечно, пользуюсь. Я и имел ввиду, что статика, которая не подгружается есть именно в той папке, которая загружается с помощью команды collectstatic

Comment: Уверены? Я бы на вашем месте перепроверил и если что то меняли, перезапустил сервис gunicorn, а в браузере воспользовался `Ctrl + F5`, чтобы обновить всю статику на стороне клиента

Comment: @Dmitry уверен, я уже несколько раз перепроверял, перезагружал gunicor, перепроверял статусы, журналы, затем перезагружал весь сервер и сбрасывал кэш в браузере - все тщетно

Comment: По логике, стили админки не подгружаются по умолчанию и это частая проблема. В `setings.py` должна быть указана `STATIC_ROOT`, следом `collectstatic` и тут нет ничего, что может сломаться и пойти не так. С `tiny.mce` нужно разбираться отдельно, поскольку это третья сторона. Не вижу, что может пойти не так, может еще кто-то поможет...

Comment: @Dmitry понял. В любом случае, благодарю за обсуждение